# common method to present UIViewControllers

Tags: swift, screen

I am trying to crate one common method to present UIViewControllers
i followed bellow steps

```
func getScreen<T>(screenID: String) -> T where T: UIViewController {

    switch screenID {
        case "ListVC":
           let ListVC = getViewController(ListVC.self, "ListVC", identifier: "ListVC")
              return ListVC as! T
        case "ListVC1":
          let ListVC1 = getViewController(ListVC1.self, "ListVC1", identifier: "ListVC1")
          return ListVC1 as! T
       default:
            return UIViewController() as! T
        }
    }
```

and use case is

```
let listVcRef = getScreen(screenId: "ListVC")
self.present(listVcRef, animated: false)
```

its working as expected till now the problem what we are facing is we are unable to access the members of ListVC from listVcRef

like

```
 let listVcRef = getScreen(screenId: "ListVC")
     listVcRef.lisstArry = [1,2,3,5]()
 self.present(listVcRef, animated: false)
```

i am getting bellow error
Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member

Can anybody help me to achieve this requirement thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how `getViewController` is implemented? Depending on how it is implemented, you might be able to simplify `getScreen` a lot.

Comment: @swwper func getViewController<T>(_ viewControllerType: T.Type, _ name: String, identifier: String) -> T where T: UIViewController {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: name, bundle: nil)
    let identifier = String(describing: identifier)
    return storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
}

Comment: Honestly, you will face more problems with this approach and it doesn't solve any so far, at least with the code what you have provided. What are you trying to accomplish? There are alternatives to Storyboard & segues, but you really need to understand these patterns, and then _correctly_ implement it, which is usually tricky.

Comment: @Vasu1604 Here is a generic way to present the controller using storyboard extension:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69115981/6576315

Answer (score 0):

Just add controller type

```
let listVcRef: ListVC = getScreen(screenId: "ListVC")
```

Also, I think you do not need to create another generic function with a switch case you can direct use ```getViewController`` funcation.

Comment: Thanks raja for answering, i want avoid this one, is there any other way we do this

Comment: No, you can't use it without type. Because you can see in your function, at the end of every line you cast ```as! T``` this means generic. And you have to set type or pass type

Comment: Ok is there any other way to achieve my requirment