# How to do hyper-dynamic typecast with "as!" in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, casting

I'm trying to do something like the following to ultimately avoid a long chain of if/else in swift.

Unfortunately, Swift isn't having it, and I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to search for the appropriate lexical representation, if there even is one.

*Note: I'm using `Any`, instead of `AnyClass` as the value type in the dictionary because for/in doesn't enumerate `AnyClass` values, and formerly I was using a loop.*

```
    var ids : [ String : Any ] =  [ "someViewControllerIdA"  : SomeViewControllerA.self,
                                    "someViewControllerIdB"  : SomeViewControllerB.self,
                                    "someViewControllerIdC"  : SomeViewControllerC.self]

    let n = 0
    let contentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ids.keys[n]) as! ids.values[n]
```

Comment: *Swift isn't having it* because it's ***unswifty***. How about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874430/creating-a-generic-uviewcontroller-initialiser)

Comment: @vadian, yup... the approach outlined in those answers *does* look Swifter.   However, I'm finding myself with a growing compendium of extensions... I'd be critical of that phenomena, except every large project I've worked on where I used C and C++ essentially  heavily customized the language and libraries with precompiler macros. It did occur to me that the solution might entail, <T, U, V> stuff but I thought impractical because then I need to define a function. Just didn't occur to me that it would be okay if as an extension.

Comment: What is `vcClass` in `as! vcClass`?

Comment: @ytrewq I edited the answer. Sorry about that. I didn't port the code to 'question' form properly.. Initially it was part of a loop.

Comment: Casting with a type only known at runtime doesn't make sense, because the casting is a purely static, compile-time concept. Every value has one immutable type at runtime. When you're casting a value from one type to another, all you're doing is making assertions as to what runtime type that is, and unlocking safe access to a particular set of properties and methods. Consider this: if you cast some value `v` to some unknown type `t` with `let castedV = v as! t`, what can you do with `castedV`? What methods can you call on it?

Comment: @Alexandar:  Thanks. Appreciate what you're saying. Makes sense in a Swift-centric view (which is what this is). I used Java Reflection plenty in the (pleasantly) *distant* past, and JavaScript and they are adaptable enough to get away with more at Runtime. True, not every cast is meaningful, but in this case I know the static compile-time class of the object I want to cast something into, but can't so I'm on the fence about whether I consider the fact that Swift can't/won't allow it a bug or a feature.  In my case it's more an exercise, not enough VCs to worry about if/then/elsing the cases.